# Where are SNMP MIBS evaluated? Can I make my own?

Tags: linux, snmp

You can monitor lots of different data points about a Linux system using SNMP, if you pick the correct MIB numbers (e.g. like .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.2.1 on http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/linuxoids.htm).

Where is the code for each MIB test stored on a Linux machine?

Is it possible to add your own custom tests? (e.g. when a custom MIB is queried, run a python script and return the response)?

Answer (score 2):

The location is *probably* dependent on your distribution; on Debian they live under `/usr/share/snmp/mibs`.  In addition to Antoine's answer on simple exec plugins for net-snmpd, you can also write more complicated plugins for net-snmpd that integrate more seamlessly; I've also written my own [Ruby SNMP agent](http://theshed.hezmatt.org/ruby-snmpd/index.html) which is designed to make it trivial to handle custom SNMP data (it's the whole reason for it's existence).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where the MIB is stored on a Linux machine but you can add the result of scripts in the default MIB by using the following syntax :

```
exec railsversion "/bin/bash /etc/snmp/railsversion.sh"
```

It will show up in your MIB which you can test by using the following command.

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8
```

This is pretty well documented in the snmpd.conf file found in Debian and probably other distros.

I find this option very useful as it eliminates the need for a specific monitoring agent.